# Is it possible to serialize JavaBeans to byte array without serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, interface, deserialization, javabeans

How can I serialize and deserialize JavaBeans without using JSON, Protobuf, Java serialization API, and other serializations? I have to implement this interface instead:

```
interface Encode
{
    byte[] serialize(Object anyBean);
    Object deserialize(byte[] byteArray);  
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You can "serialize" to a flat file e.g. CSV

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own solution but the existing APIs available are providing really good solutions, why bypassing them?

Comment: Because I was given a task not to use them.

Comment: Okay then you'll have to use reflection to access to fields and serialize them when you reach a string or a primitive type. Save the complete class name the serialized data. Store your objects in a json format, it's quite convenient.
As it sounds like a work or exercise from a school or something, don't spend too much time covering everything ;)